# Download an APK without an SD card or computer?

Tags: cyanogenmod, downloading, apk, archos-gen7

I have an Archos 7 Home Tablet v1, with a Cyanogenmod 7 rom on it. I do not have an sd card for it yet, and was wondering, Is there any way I can install/download an APK file to it without an SD card? When I try to download an APK for a market fixer, it tells me that I cannot download it without an SD card. I cannot connect to the device with my computer, because the cyanogenmod messes with the drivers. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `wget http://www.blah.com/files.apk` in the terminal emulator (if you're using CyanogenMod, then you probably have BusyBox, which includes wget), you might need root to write to the internal memory, so if you don't have write permission in the current directory, then you might need to type `su` first.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ADB to push the file onto your phone.

Comment: I have tried, and ADB doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn on "Install from unknown location" in the Applications panel? If so, I keep some APKs in my DropBox folder.